# AWS vs GoogleCloud vs DigitalOcean – Which one to choose?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cloud, digital-ocean

There is a growing startup hosted simply on a VPS at the moment.

I want to migrate it to a cloud, so I need:

- Cloud MySQL storage
- S3-compatible object storage
- In the future I'll need Docker + k8s

**Question 1: Which cloud platform should I choose: AWS, or GoogleCloud, or DigitalOcean?**

How reliable DigitalOcean is?

How complicated AWS and GoogleCloud are?

I'd love to know your experience guys! Any pros and cons are welcome.

**Question 2: In case I don't like the chosen platform, how difficult it is to migrate terabytes of data to another platform?**

What's the easiest approach to migrate huge databases?

Thank you!

Comment: We make it REALLY clear in our help pages that we don't do recommendations of any kind - they're objective and time-bound.

Comment: @Chopper3 Almost every question about any service (hosting, website, program) is subjective and time-bound. It's not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Today it’s Azure. Tomorrow it’s AWS. Next year it might be somebody running private public cloud in your next corner grocery store. Move to where it’s convenient to move in today and keep backups (Veeam in cloud?) to avoid lock-in-vendor preventing you from your next move.